# Override WebForm_OnSubmit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I need to display Validation Messages in the Validation Summary as well as show them in a  separate popup.
In order to do that I am thinking of overriding WebForm_OnSumbit method.

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
      if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {
         showErrorPopup();
         return false;
      }
    return true;
   }

   function showErrorPopup()
   {
     //Get the validation message text and append it to error popup div.
   }
```

Is it advisable to do so?
or is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The `ValidationSummary` control has two properties that affect how the validation messages are displayed.

`ShowSummary` controls whether the messages are displayed inline, as a list of errors.

`ShowMessageBox` controls whether a browser message box is displayed to show the list of errors.

These are not mutually exclusive.  If you set both to True, you will get both the inline summary and the message box.  There will be no need to write extra code.

Now, this assumes you're happy with a browser message box.  If you're not, if you want to use a jQuery-style dialog box, that will be more challenging.